# Casting in java, request.getParameter

Tags: java, html

I am trying real hard to understand why I am told that the getParameter returns an object that I need to cast it to a string in the following code? At String timeTaken I get the error Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String. I am confused as to what is causing the error, the long datatype on duration or the String datatype on user?

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long duration = t1 - t0;
    String user = request.getParameter("userName");

    String timeTaken = System.out.println("<HTML><BODY><P>Request from " + user + " at 10.10.1.123 took " + duration + "ms </P></BODY></HTML>");

    context.log(timeTaken);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` does not return anything, it just prints the value to the console. Trying to use the non existing return value and save it to timeTaken gives the error message.

You probably just want to assign the string to timeTaken;

```
String timeTaken = "<HTML><BODY><P>Request from " + user + 
     " at 10.10.1.123 took " + duration + "ms </P></BODY></HTML>";
```

and possibly on the following line if you still want to output the string too;

```
System.out.println(timeTaken);
```